# General solution of a linear functional equation

Tags: functional-equations

As we know, general solution of the linear functional equation $f(x+1)-f(x)=g(x)$ ($g$ is a known function) is $f=f_0+\phi$, where $f_0$ is an its special solution and $\phi$ any 1-periodic function.

Now, does any one know **general solution** of the linear functional equation: $$rf(ax+b)+sf(cx+d)=g(x),$$ where $a,b,c,d, r$ and $s$ are real constants with $rasc\neq0$?

($g$ is a given real function, the
case $g=0$ and the equation $f(ax+b)=cf(x)$ is of special interest).

Are there any papers or books regarding the problem?

Comment: It is the same as you wrote in the first paragraph: the general solution is the sum of a single solution plus the general solution of homogeneous equation (with g=0).

Answer (score 3):

As in the special case, the general solution is the sum of a particular solution and the general solution of the homogeneous equation.

To describe he general solution of the homogeneous equation
$$rf\phi_1+sf\circ\phi_2=0,$$
where $\phi_1(x)=ax+b$ and $\phi_2(x)=cx+d$ are affine functions, you use the fact that affine functions form a group. So there is an affine function $\phi_3$ such that
$\phi_2=\phi_3\circ\phi_1$, and making the change of the variable $t=\phi_1(x)$
we obtain the equation
$$rf(t)+sf\circ\phi_3(t)=0.$$
To further simplify this, consider two cases: a) $\phi_3(t)=at+b,\; a\neq 1$,
and b) $\phi_3(t)=t+b$. In the first case, by a conjugation in the affine group,
the equation is reduced to
$$rg(t)+sg(at)=0.$$
In the second case, it is reduced to
$$rg(t)+sg(t+1)=0.$$
The general solutions of these two standard equations must be clear.

Comment: Thanks. Can one obtain an explicit formula for the general solution from the above form?

Comment: @M.H.Hooshmand: yes, of course. This is a simple exercise.